# Put and Input function in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a data set in SAS and i want to create the following new variables by Date variable which is already present in data.

i have already written the code but i am bit of confuse in **PUT** and **INPUT** function.

Please,do have check my codes and tell me changes which i should do.

**1.Year from date variable**

**2.Month from date variable**

**3.Day from date variable**

**4.Hour from scheduled departure time variable**

### Sample data

Date      | Time

01/01/2013  | 529

05/27/2013  | 540

06/12/2013  | 600

09/28/2013  | 2025

09/30/2013  | 2040

```
data case_1.Ques_1(keep=Year Month_name Day hour);
set case_1.flights;
Year=year(Date);
month_name=put(date, monname.);
Day=put(date,downame.);
hour=put(time,hour.);
run;
```

Comment: Why are getting the name of the day of the week instead of the number of the day of the month?

Comment: Hi sir, i use downame format because the ques is asking for  day from date variable.And i think if ques is asking for day then it should be the name of day.

Answer (score 0):

Use functions here, not formats though you can. Conventionally, day usually is interpreted as day of the month, whereas you're getting the weekday or day of week instead.

This all assumes that your data is a SAS date, numeric with a date format.

```
year = year(date);
month = month(date);
month_name = put(date, monname.);
day = day(date);
weekday = put(date, downame.);
hour = hour(time);
```

`PUT()` applies a format and controls how a value is displayed.

`INPUT()` reads in a value and uses the current appearance so that the data can be read in correctly.